# setTitle not working within If statement (Like / Unlike feature)

Tags: swift

I'm working on displaying the number of "likes" a social media post has via .setTitle. I've confirmed I have the value of "count", however the if / else are not working.

I've encountered this problem while studying. Specially a tutorial to create a "clone" of Instagram. I've examined the provided code sample, comparing it to my own, however it looks identical - yet my results are different.

```
    func updateLike(post: Post) {
    let imageName = post.likes == nil || !post.isLiked! ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart_inactive") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart_active")
    likeImageView.image = imageName
    guard let count = post.likeCount else {
        return
    }
    if count != 0 {
        likeCountButton.setTitle("\(count) likes", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    } else {
        likeCountButton.setTitle("Like this post first!", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }

}
```

I expect the button title to be "Like this post first!" when count is 0, then "(count) likes" when count isn't 0

Right now the title is blank

Answer (score 1):

`guard` will return when `likeCount` is `nil` , so try

```
if let count = post.likeCount , count != 0  { 
     likeCountButton.setTitle("\(count) likes", for:.normal)
else 
    likeCountButton.setTitle("Like this post first!", for:.normal)
}
```